# Roman/Numeral Conversion in Python 3.5

Tags: python

I'm trying to work through the integer to roman numeral conversion exercise that seems to be a rite of passage for new python coders. I seem to have successfully written the integer to roman numeral part correctly but I can't get the roman numeral to integer to work correctly. In other words, when the user types "1999" the output is successfully "MCMXCIX"; however when the user types "MCMXCIX" the output is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module> rom_to_int(MCMXCIX)
NameError: name 'MCMXCIX' is not defined".
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def int_to_rom (integer):
    returnstring=''
    table=[['M',1000],['CM',900],['D',500],['CD',400],['C',100],['XC',90],['L',50],['XL',40],['X',10],['IX',9],['V',5],['IV',4],['I',1]]

    for pair in table:

        while integer-pair[1]>=0:

            integer-=pair[1]
            returnstring+=pair[0]

    return returnstring

def rom_to_int (string):
    returnint=0
    table=[['M',1000],['CM',900],['D',500],['CD',400],['C',100],['XC',90],['L',50],['XL',40],['X',10],['IX',9],['V',5],['IV',4],['I',1]]

    for pair in table:

        continueyes=True

        while continueyes:
            if len(string)>=len(pair[0]):

                if string[0:len(pair[0])]==pair[0]:
                    returnint+=pair[1]
                    string=string[len(pair[0]):]

                else: continueyes=False
            else: continueyes=False

    return returnint
```

I'm halfway there and need help troubleshooting. Can anybody see what's wrong with the second part? I've looked at other codes but they seem to be directed towards Python 2 or other coding languages. I also learned there's a python converter that easily does this now (import roman, roman.toRoman(myInt)), BUT I'm trying to practice writing functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a variable name, e.g. `var`, and a string, e.g. `'var'`?

Comment: I think it may be important to put the two letter items up front in the array to make sure CM is understood as 900 not 1100.

Comment: Python doesn't know what `MCMXCIX` is. It only knows `'MCMXCIX'` or `"MCMXCIX"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting isn't related to your code. You have

```
rom_to_int(MCMXCIX)
```

but since you don't have quotes around `MCMXCIX`, it takes it to be an (undefined) variable and throws the error you see.